# How to satisfy strict mime type checking for wasm?

Tags: webpack, browser, server, webassembly

I got a webassembly module to compile using emscripten. Now I'm trying to serve it up in a web page using expressjs.

I've tried following [this gist](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/wasm-simple) on including webassembly via webpack, including a modification I found since this gist is a little older.

The webpack looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    mangleWasmImports: false
  },
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    filename: 'dynamic-graph.bundle.js'
  },
  target: "web",
  module: {
    rules: [
      // Emscripten JS files define a global. With `exports-loader` we can 
      // load these files correctly (provided the global’s name is the same
      // as the file name).
      {
        test: /fourd\.js$/,
        loader: "exports-loader"
      },
      // wasm files should not be processed but just be emitted and we want
      // to have their public URL.
      {
        test: /fourd\.wasm$/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          publicPath: "dist/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I set up https on the dev-server, because I know that sometimes causes issues. It's a self signed certificate, but Chrome and Firefox let me get around that.

```js
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
express.static.mime.types['wasm'] = 'application/wasm'
const https = require('https')
const app = express()

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
  next()
})
https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app).listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('Listening...')
})
```

In a previous version, I was able to use Module.onRuntimeInitialized to wait for the wasm module to be instantiated. That code still works, I compiled the webpack using the same em++ flags as before, namely `-std=c++11 -s WASM=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s SAFE_HEAP=1 -O0 -g4 -s ASSERTIONS=1`

The error I get in the browser is the following: `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/wasm". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` which throws me for a loop, because I thought application/wasm is exactly what the MIME type should be.

Comment: I've tried this with Apache, with expressjs and with python's simplehttpserver.

Answer (score 0):

`application/wasm` is indeed the correct MIME type to use for WASM files. The problem is that the WASM isn't being imported the proper way, through `WebAssembly.instantiate[Streaming]`. Instead, it is imported with:

```js
import { add } from "./add.wasm";
```

Normally, this gets transpiled to a `WebAssembly.instantiate` call, but this isn't happening. Instead, the module is being served without the `import`s being transpiled to proper importing. Make sure you are transpiling the JavaScript, and not just serving it as a static file, as seems to be the case in that code. Alternatively, you could make the `WebAssembly.instantiate` call yourself.